# setTheme() not completely overriding manifest application theme

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme

I have set up two different themes, one extending `Theme.AppCompat` and the other extending `Theme.AppCompat.Light`:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat"></style>
<style name="MyTheme.Light" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>
```

In my Manifest file I have put one of the two:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme.Light">
```

However I want user to be able to switch between themes, so I'm overriding this parameter in the `onCreate()` method of my activity: I retrieve which theme to set from `SharedPreference`s, and then set it up with `setTheme(int id)`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    loadTheme();
    setContentView(R.layout.a_main);
}

public void loadTheme() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String key = "theme";
    String theme = prefs.getString(key, getDefault(key));
    if (theme.equals("dark")) {
        setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
    } else { setTheme(R.style.MyTheme_Light); }
}
```

This works fine for probably all the theme values, **with the exception** of the background color (should be `android:windowBackground`). That color value is not affected by my `setTheme()` call, and stays the values I put in the manifest file.

I.e., if I set `@style/MyTheme.Light` background will always be white-ish, no matter what I do with `setTheme()`. Similarly, if I set `@style/MyTheme` in the manifest my background will stay dark.
Why is it, and what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your alternate theme includes changes to the Window, you'll need to call `setTheme` before the call to `super.onCreate(..)`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    loadTheme();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a_main);
}

public void loadTheme() {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String key = "theme";
    String theme = prefs.getString(key, getDefault(key));
    if (theme.equals("dark")) {
        setTheme(R.style.MyTheme);
    } else { setTheme(R.style.MyTheme_Light); }
}
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as I agree with yours.

Comment: I didn't have time to test this and I won't have any in the next few days, but it looks reasonable. Thank you.

Comment: Great approach for dark theme implementation.

Comment: These XML theme staff just aren't working for me. Tried to do different staff, but most of the solutions like this just don't seem to work. Pretty much stuck.